# GStreamer demo deosn't work in Virtual Machine (seeking simple example)

Tags: virtual-machine, gstreamer

I am tryign to code an extremely simple GStreamer app. It doesn't matter what it does, so long as GStreamer does something. Even just displaying some text or a simple JPEG would be fine.

Below is about the best example that I could find by Googling (I have added a few error checks). When I run it in a Linux Virtual Machine running under Windows, I see this console message:

> libEGL warning: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
>
> libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open vboxvideo (search paths
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)

Googling indicates that this is an error with 3D rendering inside a virtual machine. I can find no solution.

So, can someone fix the code below so that it will run in a VM? I assume that that would mean avoiding 3D rendering, so maybe display an image or some text? It is not necessary to play video, this is just a simple proof of concept of using GStreamer inside something else (which has to be running in a VM).

Here's the code ...

```
void GstreamerPlayVideo()
{
      GstElement *pipeline;
      GstBus *bus;
      GstMessage *msg;
      int argc;
      GError *error = NULL;

      /* Initialize GStreamer */
      if (gst_init_check(&argc, NULL, &error) == TRUE)
      {

          /* Build the pipeline */
          // Change URL to test failure
          pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("bin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", &error);
////          pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("bin uri=http://tecfa.unige.ch/guides/x3d/www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/HelloWorld.gif", &error);

          if (pipeline != NULL)
          {
              /* Start playing */
              gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

              /* wait until it's up and running or failed */
              if (gst_element_get_state (pipeline, NULL, NULL, -1) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
              {
                 g_error ("GST failed to go into PLAYING state");
                 exit(1);
              }

              /* Wait until error or EOS */
              bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
              if (bus != NULL)
              {
                  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

                  /* Parse message */
                  if (msg != NULL)
                  {
                    gchar *debug_info;

                    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg))
                    {
                      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
                        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug_info);
                        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), error->message);
                        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
                        g_clear_error (&error);
                        g_free (debug_info);
                        break;

                      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
                        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
                        break;

                      default:
                        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
                        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    gst_message_unref (msg);
                  }

                  /* Free resources */
                  gst_object_unref (bus);
                  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
                  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
              }
              else
              {
                    g_print ("GST get bus error: %s\n", error->message);
                    exit(1);
              }
          }
          else
          {
                g_print ("GST parse error: %s\n", error->message);
                exit(1);
          }
      }
      else
      {
            g_print ("GST init error: %s\n", error->message);
            exit(1);
      }
}   // GstreamerPlayVideo()
```

Comment: could you try to run gst-launch-1.0 with [some pipeline](http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Gstreamer_cheat_sheet)? at least gst-launch-1.0 --version just to know which gstreamer are you using.. what is [OpenGL version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Gstreamer n00b. Can you expand on that? Help me code it?

Comment: well I mean just go to your shell and type:
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ximagesink

Comment: for the code why dont you try something like [this](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735) they are also ported(to newer gstreamer) [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a video sink by hand in your pipeline.

> > videotestsrc ! ximagesink

Your system may have an EGL video sink plugin installed as the primary video plugin.  ximagesink seems a little more likely to work.

Like this:

```
//this line is where you're creating your pipeline
pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("videotestsrc ! ximagesink", &error);
```

I recommend experimenting with the gst-launch command first so you can get a hang of pipeline syntax, what sinks and sources are, etc.  The simplest test you can run is something like this (if you have gstreamer 1.0 installed, you may have 0.10), from the command line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Please accept my apologies for not replying sooner. I have been ill. Can you tell me how to implement your solution in the code above

Comment: I guess that we will never know :-(